# How to create a custom annotation like @PathVariable that modifies/provides the value of a method parameter

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to make a custom annotation that like @PathVariable, will be used on a parameter to provide values to a method like so:

```
public String subscribe(@PathVariable String date, @PathVariable String text, @PermittedMarkets String[] marketCodes) { //do processing and return something here }
```

I have defined the annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PermittedMarkets {

}
```

and:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MarketsAspect {
    @Value("#{${config.market.permitted.marketmapping:{:}}}") //if value is provided, use it or default to empty map
    private Map<String,String> roleToMarketCodeMap;

    @Before("@annotation(com.org.app.service.security.annotation.PermittedMarkets)")
    public String[] before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        final var grantedAuthorities =
                Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
                        .map(Authentication::getAuthorities)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new AccessDeniedException("No authorities found"));

        return grantedAuthorities.stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .filter(entitlement -> entitlement.contains("app_user"))
                .map(A_entitlement -> roleToMarketCodeMap.get(A_entitlement))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

However, when I step through using a debugger, this is what is shown on the subscribe method:

[image]

The debugger does not enter the before() method at all, even with a breakpoint on it.

Comment: What is your issue? You want to debug in `before` or your code in `before` does not execute? Does the logic inside `before` execute? Try to print log inside to check.

Comment: Seems overpowered. Why you not simply calling a method in your controller or service?

Comment: @D.T I put debug points on the before method, and inside the before method. None of the break points were reached.

Comment: @akop I looked into your suggestion, and using the reflectUtil in the suggested answer seemed much more verbose. I am considering if I should make a modification to the code base to autowire the SecurityContextHolder/Authentication although it may not follow the existing practices from my team as it would be way more convenient.

Comment: but based on the two links I mentioned, I did manage to get it working using an @Around annotation and changing the code accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Please read through the documentation : [Supported Pointcut Designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/ataspectj/pointcuts.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> @args: Limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when
> using Spring AOP) where the runtime type of the actual arguments
> passed have annotations of the given types.

The PCD to be used is `@args`

Comment: Oh, I just found these 2 links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312242/21324690 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676150/21324690. I ll try it out now, but i suspect my question to be a duplicate